# Script produces no output

Tags: python

This program is to calculate the check digit of a credit card number using Luhn's algorithm but when I run nothing appears and it keeps executing cell on jupyter notebook.

```
data = "401288888888188" #do not edit this 15 digit String
checkdigit = 0 #integer data type

#Debug the following code
index = 0
sum = 0

while index <= len(data):
   if index % 2 == 0:
      if int(data[index]) * 2 > 9:
         sum = sum + int(data[index]) * 2 - 9
      else:
         sum = sum + int(data[index]) * 2
   else :
      sum = sum + int(data[index])

    
i = sum % 10
checkdigit = 10 - i

print(checkdigit)
```

Comment: is index supposed to stay on 0? because it seems like you've created a endless loop.

Comment: you are not changing `index` anytime in the loop, so this is always satisfied: `while index <= len(data)`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You code is missing the increment of the `index` variable inside the `while` loop, so the code is still running. You also have to subtract 1 from the `len(data)` or you will get the index out of range exception

Answer (score 1):

1. Increment index variable inside while loop.
2. while index < len(data) instead of <= as index sharts from 0

Here is the modified code:

```
data = "401288888888188" #do not edit this 15 digit String
checkdigit = 0 #integer data type

#Debug the following code
index = 0
sum = 0
l = len(data)
while index < len(data):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        if int(data[index]) * 2 > 9:
            sum = sum + int(data[index]) * 2 - 9
        else:
            sum = sum + int(data[index]) * 2
    else :
        sum = sum + int(data[index])
    index += 1


i = sum % 10
checkdigit = 10 - i

print(checkdigit)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at the while loop for your code. You can see that the index number is not being updated, this means your code will never end as it is not adding to the index variable.